# Is it possible to change all fill colours together without CSS?

Tags: svg

Imagine an SVG image with multiple `<path>`

Is it possible to set a single `fill="#abc"` in the HTML of SVG (not separate CSS) that would apply to all its paths (instead of adding it to each path)?

Comment: all fill is CSS, that's just an attribute that maps to a CSS property. What exactly is your issue with CSS here? Is your SVG a separate file or inline in the html page? A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the SVG for WebExtension context-menu icon in Firefox browser. There is no access to change it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<svg fill="#88f195" width="400" height="400">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  <rect x="50" y="120" width="300" height="100" style="stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

You can set `fill` property of an svg element.